# AngularJS - template from variable

Tags: angularjs

Tried to read about $compile, $parse and $eval however cannot get understand how to store a template in a variable then use it during rendering processes.

What I would like to achieve:

code:

```
const data = {
   template: 'test {{foo}} some text {{bar}}',
}
```

html:

```
<p> some text </p>
<h1> <included in here: data.template> </h1>
```

result:

```
<p> some text </p>
<h1> test ... some text ... </h1>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simple way you can create an `html` file for your template and use `ng-include` directive, so `ng-include` directive will the thing for you out of the box

**my-template.html**

```
<div>
  <p> some text </p>
  <h1> <included in here: data.template> </h1>
</div>
```

Or you can also create an `ng-template` on html page itself like shown below

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
    <div>
      <p> some text </p>
      <h1> <included in here: data.template> </h1>
    </div>
</script>
```

**Usage:**

```
Your consumer page
<ng-include 
  src="'my-template.html'">
</ng-include>
```

---

I understand by this solution you can end up creating multiple `template` html file or script templates. So other way around to solve this problem you can create your own directive and compile the content manually and render it inside a DOM manually.

**Directive**

```
.directive("dynamicContent", function($compile, $parse){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var linkFn = $parse(attrs.template);
            var content = linkFn(scope)
            // creating template wrapper around 
            var wrapper = `<div>${content}</div>`
            var tempate = $compile(wrapper)(scope)
            element.append(tempate);
        }
    }
});
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fs587w0h9CSC7RhEmJdB?p=preview)

Comment: @pankaj-parker thank you! I knew about first two approaches, however the directive with plunker has shown me the way to achieve my final solution. I have learned a lot about $parse() and $compile() from this example. Finally I have used:
            element.html(content);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);